# Winapi: GetTickCount() can't get ELAPSED TIME

Tags: winapi, counter, elapsedtime

Hi I got a simple FPS counter in my animation. FPS counts fine but I don't know why I can't measure the animation time. Normaly I get that time by `glutGet(GLUT ELAPSED TIME)` but since I have to go Winapi I would like to (or must) use `GetTickCount()` Here is my code:

```
int Frames=0;
int CurrentTime=0;
int PreviousTime=0;
int IntervalTime=0;
int CounterTime=0;
float FPS;

void fpscount(){
    Frames++;
    CurrentTime = GetTickCount();
    IntervalTime = CurrentTime - PreviousTime;

    if(IntervalTime >= 1000)
    {
        FPS = Frames / (IntervalTime / 1000.0f);
        PreviousTime = CurrentTime;
        Frames = 0;
        CounterTime += IntervalTime;

    }
}
```

I measure by line: `CounterTime += IntervalTime;` and get strange values like:
44834406 
44835420

If I define that line as `CounterTime = IntervalTime+CounterTime;` the `CounterTime` gets values as above.

If I define that line as `CounterTime = IntervalTime;` the `CounterTime` gets values:
1014
1014
but they are are not summed.

The correct values should be:
1014
2028
.
.
.

What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: GetTickCount is not a reliable option for this kind of calculation. See GetTickCount as a fast way to time code portion when doing optimisations. But don't rely on it for something like FPS calculations. It works but the call to the function cost and precision is not enough. timeGetTime() is a better option better resolution but need some more linking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
int Frames = 0;
DWORD PreviousTime = 0;
float FPS = 0.0f;

void fpscount()
{
    Frames++;

    DWORD CurrentTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD IntervalTime = (CurrentTime >= PreviousTime)
        ? (CurrentTime - PreviousTime)
        : ((MAXDWORD - PreviousTime) + CurrentTime);

    if (IntervalTime >= 1000)
    {
        FPS = Frames / (IntervalTime / 1000.0f);
        PreviousTime = CurrentTime;
        Frames = 0;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to initialize `PreviousTime` with the current time when you first start processing frames.

Comment: Hi I have used your code, can you look at this: [link]http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/231/b/2/rfes_by_nightkn8-d6ix9xd.png the (fake) results in red frame are my main question and problem. Btw. your code seems better than one I'm using :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't follow your thought pattern, but the way I do it is like so:

```
int gFpsStartTime;
int gFpsEndTime;
int gFpsFrames;
float gFPS;

void fpscount(){
    if (gFpsEndTime == 0) gFpsEndTime = GetTickCount();
    gFpsStartTime = GetTickCount();
    ++gFpsFrames;
    if (gFpsStartTime - gFpsEndTime > 0) {
        gFPS = gFpsFrames / ((gFpsStartTime - gFpsEndTime) / 1000.0f);
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of giving you fractions of FPS too, which gives a better average.

Comment: How can I get specific time from your code above? for example in third second from the animation start the fps was = 60.00 or in fourth second do...sth.

Comment: If you're trying to do animation, you'd simply take the `GetTickCount()`, and modulate it by the total time of your animation and divide it by the number of frames.  If you are not talking about animation, then I'm unsure what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising `IntervalTime` like this:

```
CurrentTime = GetTickCount();
IntervalTime = CurrentTime - PreviousTime;
```

But on the very first iteration, `PreviousTime` is 0. This means that on the first iteration, `IntervalTime` is assigned the value of `GetTickCount()`, which is the number of milliseconds since the system was booted.

You need to initialise `PreviousTime` to `GetTickCount()` when your animation starts playing.

Comment: You also need to take into account what happens when `GetTickCount()` wraps back to 0 every 49.7 days that Windows has been running continuously. Either account for the wrapping, or use `GetTickCount64()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [timeGetTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for better timer precision.